# Are there cases where the use of the Grassmann variables simplifies computations in the usual bosonic analysis?

Tags: fermions, mathematics, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

When one introduces complex numbers and complex analysis one can then use the new machinery to solve some real-analysis problems. A lamppost example is computing integrals via residues.

I think I've heard not once the same about Grassmann numbers as another extension of the real numbers. Are there some simple bosonic problems that are solved much easier with introduction of Grassmann calculus?

I was recently exposed to a SUSY course which focused not on fundamental SUSY, but on a kind of SUSY emerging in a specific description (say of disordered systems). Another example would be Faddeev-Popov ghosts. I now would like to put what I learned into perspective and find some toy examples that would show clearly how introduction of auxiliary Grassmann variables could be useful.

Comment: @Qmechanic Hm I'm not sure how to make the question more precise. Description of fermions is a physical problem. Superfield computations imply that you have a Grassmann variables to begin with, right? If we go back to the complex numbers analogy I would give an example of the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos \alpha z}{1+z^2}=\pi e^{|\alpha|}$ as something that is simpler to do using complex numbers, although the problem was defined purely over reals. Are there similarly simple examples where the introduction of Grassmann variables is beneficial?

Answer (score 2):

Determinants and [Pfaffians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian) via [Gaussian Grassmann integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berezin_integral) are typical applications that have some benefits. This is e.g used in the Faddeev-Popov determinant already mentioned by OP.

*Example.* Try to prove that ${\rm Det}(A)~=~{\rm Pf}(A)^2$ for an antisymmetric matrix $A$ [with](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2705327/11127) vs. without the use of Gaussian Grassmann integrals.

More generally, there are [exterior calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra), [exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative), [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form), [cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomology) and [homology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_(mathematics)), but there the Grassmann variables are often there from the very beginning.

Comment: Yep, Grassmann variables can sure handle some antisymmetrization for you (say proving that Pfaffian squares to a Determinant). But this I think is relatively trivial, especially if your are good with Levi-Civita symbols:) Are you aware of other examples, perhaps of a different character?